# Extend Admin template CSS in django

Tags: python, css, django

On my django site I tried unsuccesfully to change the color and a little of CSS of the header bar in the django admin site. I don't want to change anything else.

The template I currently have:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block extrastyle %}
<style>
    #header{ background-color: #a67d3d; border-bottom: solid 3px #f5deb3; }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

This modifies the colors but makes the rest of the content blank. Navigating through the urls I managed to go beyond the main screen only to find the base colors (the blue I'm trying to change) and everything else working.

I also tried using: `{% extends "admin/base.html" %}` to no avail.

Is there a way to do this without creating a completly new Admin instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably as to do with the fact that your override code is not at the right place. So,

1. Go under your project directory and create a folder called `templates`
2. Add another directory called `admin`
3. Create a file called `base_site.html` and add your code

So, the code you posted in your question should reside in,

```
YourProject/templates/admin/base_site.html
```

Then, the override should appear correclty.

Comment: Thank you ver much!. If i want to do this with the login. The file should be there and be named login.html?